# why image is not inserting in database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

NO VALue specified for parameter 2 even i had used inputstream
and used setBlob method---
 NO VALue specified for parameter 2 even i had used inputstream
and used setBlob method--
 NO VALue specified for parameter 2 even i had used inputstream
and used setBlob method---

here is my jsp code:

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="insertbooks">
<p>Title<p>
<input type="text" style="width:300px;height:25px" name="title" placeholder="Type Book Title"/>
<p>Insert image</p>
<input name="image" type="file">
<p>Author</p>
<input type="text" style="width:300px;height:25px" name="author" placeholder="Author Name"/>
<p>Price</p>
<input type="text" style="width:300px;height:25px" name="price" placeholder="Enter price"/>
<br>

<br><br>
<input style="width:100px;height:35px;font-size:1.3em" type="submit" name="submitb" value="submit" />
</form>
```

this is my insertbooks.java code :

```
public class insertbooks extends HttpServlet {

private String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookecom";    
private String dbUser = "root";
private String dbPass = "";

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

     // for error handling in file
    File file=new File("D://Study//programming//servlet//bookecom//insertbookserror.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    //retrieving image
   InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file
    String Title = request.getParameter("title");

     // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
    Part filePart = request.getPart("image");
    if (filePart != null) {
        // prints out some information for debugging
        System.out.println(filePart.getName());
        System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
        System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

        // obtains input stream of the upload file
         inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        pw.println("Got photooo");
    }

//    System.out.println(" filename:  "+filePart.getName());
  //  pw.println(filePart.getName());
    String Author = request.getParameter("author");
    String Pricef = request.getParameter("price");

    //float Pricef = Float.valueOf(Price);
      pw.println("Got parameters");

      System.out.println("price value"+Pricef);

  Connection conn = null;


  try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        pw.println("Driver Loaded");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass); 
        pw.println("Connection Established_1");


 // String query = "Insert into books(title,image,author,price) values('"+Title +"','"+inputStream +"','"+Author+"','"+Pricef +"')" ;
 String query = "Insert into books(title,image,author,price) values(?,?,?,?)" ;

 PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement(query);
 ps.setString(1,Title);
    if(inputStream != null){
    // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
 ps.setBlob(2, inputStream);
    } else{  pw.println(" blob data not available");  }
 ps.setString(3,Author);
 ps.setString(4, Pricef);



 // Sends the statement to the database server
 int row= ps.executeUpdate();
 if(row>0){
 pw.println("data inserted");

 }

  } catch (SQLException ex) {
         ex.getMessage();
      //  ex.printStackTrace();
      ex.printStackTrace(pw);
        pw.println("Connection not Established_1");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(insertbooks.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            // closes the database connection
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Successfully");
        // sets the message in request scope
      //  request.setAttribute("message", message);

        // forwards to the message page
       // getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

pw.close();
}
}
```

these are error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1132)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1057)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1377)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1042)
at insertbooks.doPost(insertbooks.java:90)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't store the images in the database, the best way to store files is to save them in the server and store the file name in the database. If you need the image, get the file name stored in the DB and get the image from the server.
2. If you really needd to store the image in the DB, try to put all the code after the if statement asking if the filePart is null inside the if, like this:

   `if (filePart != null) {
       System.out.println(filePart.getName());
       System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
       System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());
        inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
       pw.println("Got photooo");
       //PUT ALL THE CODE AFTER THIS IF STATEMENT HERE
   }`